# How to get data without index number in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting the value [1] 0.7976529 by using `verbatimTextOutput("oaccura")` on ui.r and `output$oaccura<-renderPrint({a3})` 
on server.r but i want 0.7976529. How to get data and add dynamic css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use `renderText` instead

```
library(shiny)
a3 <- 0.7976529
ui  <- fluidPage(verbatimTextOutput("oaccura"))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$oaccura <- renderText({a3})
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

[image]